# Swap image on page load

Tags: jquery, refresh, swap

a simple question I think but not one i can find much on baring in mind I'm not too good with jquery.

I would like to simply have images as such:

```
<img class="banner-rotate" src="images/image1.gif" />
<img class="banner-rotate" src="images/image2.gif" />
<img class="banner-rotate" src="images/image3.gif" />
<img class="banner-rotate" src="images/image4.gif" />
```

On load of the page I would like to show the first image then cycle through them in order on every refresh of the page.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you use cookies (even if I think it's not a good idea if this is the only thing you'll put on it)? Can you use some local storage (but you'll have to get in trouble with browsers compatibility)? What server side environment are you using (JSP? PHP? ASP.NET?). Somewhere you have to store what's the last viewed image index.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to store the previous client state somewhere (typically cookie or local storage) so you can advance to the next image each time the page is loaded.  This example uses a cookie value:

HTML:

```
<img class="banner-rotate" src="images/image1.gif" />
<img class="banner-rotate" src="images/image2.gif" />
<img class="banner-rotate" src="images/image3.gif" />
<img class="banner-rotate" src="images/image4.gif" />
```

CSS:

```
/* all banner images hidden by default */
.banner_rotate {display: none;}
```

Javascript:

```
// cookie reading/writing library
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function showNextBannerImage() {
    var imgs = $(".banner-rotate");
    var index = 0;
    var prev = readCookie("bannerIndex");
    if (prev) {
        var num = parseInt(prev, 10);
        if (!isNaN(num) && num < imgs.length - 1) {
            index = num + 1;
        }
    }
    imgs.eq(index).show();
    createCookie("bannerIndex", index, 365);
}

showNextBannerImage();
```

Note: I used your HTML as you showed it, but you don't have to load all the images in order to show just one.  You could compute the desired image URL and use javascript to create the image tag with the appropriate URL and then only load that one image.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to use localStorage/sessionStorage or cookies or an ajax Request to remember the image, which was last shown.

You also need only one `img`-Tag, where you change the src-attribute accordingly.

a simple solution would be:

```
var index = localStorage.getItem("index");
var imageCount = 4;
if ( index === null){
    index = 1;
    localStorage.setItem("index",index);
}
else{
    var newVal = index%imageCount+1;
    localStorage.setItem("index",newVal);
}

$(".banner-rotate").attr("src","images/image"+index+".gif");
```

Note, this only works in modern browsers, since localStorage is not available in old browsers ( mainly IE<=7). For those Browsers you need a fallback via cookies.

Comment: This just increases the index value by one every time the page loads and keeps on going forever.  It has no sense of the max number of images available so it can wrap back to the first image when it has already done the last one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't mean to remember the last image shown before the page refresh. What you want is just simply cycle through the images on every page load. Am I right?

If yes, you can do this - http://jsfiddle.net/BHrHS/

```
var d;

$("img.banner-rotate").each(function(i) {
    d = i * 2000;

    $(this).delay(d).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(this).fadeOut(1000);
    });
});​
```